# INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ARITHABORT'

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jtds

I have read the topics in Stackoverflow about this problem, but I really haven't a solution yet.

My problem is sending a String or Clob as an XML parameter in a Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2008. I'm using jTDS to connect it. I've read that I have to set the "ARITHABORT" to ON, but I really don't know where I can do it.

Maybe in my own session in JAVA or in DB too... Please help!! (And sorry for my very very bad english)

Ok! Here is the method that is giving me the error:

```
   private static final String PR_SV_MUDA_STATUS_EVENTO_CONCLUIDO = "{CALL PR_SV_MUDA_STATUS_EVENTO_CONCLUIDO(?, ?, ?, ?)}";


   public String modificaStatus(Connection connection, Integer eventoRobo, String path) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;

    conn = GenericHibernateDAO.criaConexao();


    CallableStatement cs2 = conn.prepareCall(PR_SV_MUDA_STATUS_EVENTO_CONCLUIDO);

    cs2.setInt(1, eventoRobo);
    cs2.setString(2, null);
    cs2.setString(3, null);
    cs2.setString(4, path);
    cs2.execute();
    conn.close();

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code that you tried to achieve your goal and have problems with, that would help getting a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the query

```
  SET ARITHABORT ON;
```

This needs to be run before your stored procedure. Either you can run it soon after getting the connection.

Once the processing is done, you may want to run the query below.

```
  SET ARITHABORT OFF;
```

These queries can be run using additional statements in your java program.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you please share few lines from the top of the error stacktrace?

Comment: I've just come across this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305333 which indicates the SET ARITHABORT should be run in its own batch.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem today and got it solved. I created a filtered index on a column in sql server 2008 r2, but would get this error when inserting. Saw this question wasn't completely answered since it might be tedious to always turn arithabort on in every insert. I found a blog that showed it was the database compatibility level that was the issue. Changed the compatibility level from 80 (2000) to 100 (2008) and the issue was solved. not sure if changing the compatibility level to 90 would solve this or not, but worth a try.

SQL Server compatibility levels and command to change here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx

If this doesn't work or you can't change the compatibility mode there is another workaround by adding a trigger in the blog I was talking about here http://chrismay.org/2013/05/23/interesting-problem-with-sql-server-arithabort-filtered-indexes-calculated-columns-and-compatibility-mode-of-80/

Note that this change was done on a test database, and all applications should be tested before making a change like this in production. Make sure this is ok with your DBA before changing too.